# Converting bigint to timestamp in presto

Tags: date, time, timestamp, bigint, presto

I have a column in my dataset that has a datatype of bigint:

```
Col1     Col2
   1     1519778444938790
   2     1520563808877450
   3     1519880608427160
   4     1520319586578960
   5     1519999133096120
```

How do I convert Col2 to the following format:

year-month-day  hr:mm:ss

I am not sure what format my current column is in but I know that it is supposed to be a timestamp.

Any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried to use functions like `from_unixtime`? You could use it to convert unix time to timestamp, then you could use `date_format` to display it in way you want. Notice that in your example your unix time is with microseconds, so you might want to convert it first to milliseconds.

I have not tested that but I am assuming that your code should look like:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(col2/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Notice that `from_unixtime` accepts also a time zone.

Please visit this page to see the more details about date related functions: https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe the denominator should be 1000000 not 1000. Probably a typo. Anyways juts adding the test results here for others reference.

-- Microseconds

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(cast('1519778444938790' as bigint)/1000000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

2018-02-28 12:40:44

Answer (score 1):

If you need to filter the data where the column is in BIGINT Unix format, then you can use the following snippet to compare : `from_unixtime(d.started_on /1000) >= CAST('2022-05-10 22:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP )`

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is a bit misleading. You should divide by 1000.0 otherwise you'll lose ms precision and be limited to second precision:

date_format(from_unixtime(col2/1000.0), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')